# How can I tell MathJax to process just one node?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I want to run MathJax on my page, but I only want it to process a single node, say a node stored in a Javascript variable called `mathNode`. How can I do this? I've caught wiffs when reading the docs that suggest this may be possible - a single reference to the code

```
var math = document.getElementById("MathExample");
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,math]);
```

which will supposedly do the sort of thing I want, but I haven't been able to find any concrete, usable information on where this code should go or what else needs to be done. I've tried various combinations of listening for startup hooks and calling `MathJax.Hub.Config`, but ultimately I'm just groping around in the dark - the docs just don't seem to cover this usecase.

Is there a way I can do what I'm trying to do?

I'm not interested in `ignoreClass` and `processClass` solutions - I need a solution which only assumes I'm able to get a reference in JS to the element or elements I want processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this script tag before the script tag which inserts `MathJax.js`:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config(
        {
            elements: /* array of HTML elements to be processed */,
        }
    );
</script>
```